# Python 3.7 Window 10 Service Not Working: Error starting service: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

Tags: python-3.x

I have write a simple python 3.7 window service and installed successfully.Now I am facing this error
"Error starting service: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion."

Please Help me to fix this error.

Thanks

Comment: Have waste 7 days to fixed this error using different tech but failed.

Comment: Hi Maria. Welcome to SO. It would be easier to help you if you show what you have tried, alongwith the full Traceback error message

Answer (score 0):

One of the most common errors from windows when starting your service is Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion. This can occur for multiple reasons but there are a couple things to check when you do get them:

Make sure your service is actually stopping:Note the `main` method has an infinite loop. The template above with break the loop if the stop even occurs, but that will only happen if you call `win32event.WaitForSingleObject` somewhere within that loop; setting `rc` to the updated value
Make sure your service actually starts: Same as the first one, if your service starts and does not get stuck in the infinite loop, it will exit. Terminating the service
Check your system and user PATH contains the necessary routes: The DLL path is extremely important for your python service as its how the script interfaces with windows to operate as a service. Additionally if the service is unable to load python - you are also hooped. Check by typing `echo %PATH%` in both a regular console and a console running with Administrator priveleges to ensure all of your paths have been loaded
Give the service another restart: Changes to your `PATH` variable may not kick in immediately - its a windows thing